# Angular app acting weird

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all, i am new to angular so, the problem i have, might be a simple and stupid thing i did wrong, i am aware of that :) But here it is:

I have an angular app which started to act weird. I don't know how to explain this properly, but let's say i have 2 computers with the app open in a browser (doesn't matter which browser) and if on one computer the user scrolls or types something in that page, in a form field, those changes will be replicated on the second computer too. It looks like i have remote control over the other browsers.

I don't know what the problem is, but i believe it might be that these inputs from a user are done directly on the server side and not on the client side.
Can you guys give me some hints, where to look or what to check in my code to find the cause of this?

I can update this question with some code too, but i don't know what would help..

Thank you!

EDIT: i am adding parts of my code as requested in comments:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "LicenseRef-LICENSE",
  "author": "me",
  "description": "App",
  "keywords": [
    "express",
    "gulp",
    "angular"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.12.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.7.13",
    "del": "^1.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-protractor": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-if-else": "^1.0.3",
    "gulp-install": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-config": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-protractor-qa": "^0.1.17",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-uncss": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-usemin": "^0.3.11",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "jshint": "2.5.10",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "phantomjs": "1.9.18",
    "request": "^2.60.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: You should show us your controller and app.js. Also the package.json would help spot if you have some tool to synchronise views.

Comment: i added the code as requested

Comment: You are using browser sync (I can see it from your package.json) which probably is the reason your app behaves like you described. You should have it initiated in your gulpfile.js

Comment: @thepio you are right! it was the browser sync plugin! i got rid of it at the moment. thank you! i don't know how to mark your comment as the right answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your package.json I can see that you have included browser sync plugin in your application. Browser sync is the cause of this behavior.

Browser sync official webpage: https://www.browsersync.io/

You can find your initialization of browser sync in your gulpfile.js since I can also see that you are using gulp in your project.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check: Open your browser developer tools and check if there is websocket activity. If no check if your browser makes http requests(http polling) at certain interval.

Comment: i did a check and i haven't seen abnormal activity regarding websockets or http requests

Comment: You need to check websocket activity while making changes to the page(changes which cause other browser to be updated), have you done it that way ?

Answer (score 0):

@thepio gave me the right answer in a comment. i don't know how to mark that as the answer, but for anyone else who wants to find out, it was the browser-sync plugin that did it. i disabled it in gulp.

Comment: Hi Christian. I made my comment into an answer so you can give me credit if you wish. Don't have to though, you can mark your own answer accepted also. Let me know and I will remove my answer :)

Comment: No problem and thank you! You can even delete this (your own) answer because it's not really an answer. If you wish to follow the rules of SO of course ;P